# How to correctly write $\max$

Tags: optimization, convention

Recently I came across some Economics notes which wrote the profit maximization equation as follows:

$\underset{p}\max \; \pi = p.q(p) - p.c(p)$

where, $p$ is the price, $q(p)$ is the quantity at that price and $c(p)$ is the cost at the given price.

I think that the $\max$ on the LHS is not meaningful as there is no $p$ there and it is more correct/meaningful to write the equation as follows.

$\pi = \underset{p}\max \; p.q(p) - p.c(p)$

Are there any conventions/guidelines for this? Are they both equivalent?

Comment: First step towards the *correct* way is to write `\max` and not `max` when using $\rm\LaTeX$.

Comment: Point well taken!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to express the term on the rhs gets maximal if you plug in $p=π$, you can use [argmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max), like:

$$\pi = \underset{p}{\text{argmax}} ( pq(p) - pc(p)).$$

If you want to express that π is the maximum of the rhs write: 
$$\pi = \underset{p}{\text{max}} ( pq(p) - pc(p)).$$

The term $\underset{p}{\max} \pi$ is well-defined, too. And it is  $$\underset{p}{\max} \pi = \pi.$$
Hence: 
$$ \underset{p}{\text{max}}\pi =  pq(p) - pc(p) \qquad ⇔\qquad \pi =  pq(p) - pc(p)$$

which is most likely not what you want to express.

Comment: I agree with this answer (typo "the the"). Since the question was how to correctly write "max," I would say also write $\max$ and not $max$.

Comment: Thx @Ron. I also added the part about $\max$ being on the lhs, to complete this answer.